# is IBM MQ 9.2 compatible with JMS 1.5 or need JMS2.0 to work with?

Tags: ibm-mq

One of our end application which has JMS lower version want to connect to IBM MQ upgraded version V9.2. Can it still use old version of JMS or upgrade to new version 2.0?

Comment: MQ 8.0 and later require the 2.0 jms.jar, but JMS 2.0 should function fine with JMS 1.1 code.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you are making a network connection, the version of MQ on the client machine and the version of MQ on the Queue Manager machine do not have to be the same. If your Queue Manager is a V9.2, your client can still use MQ V7.5 and JMS 1.1 if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ v8.0 and later require the JMS 2.0 jms.jar.

IBM MQ 7.5 and lower require the JMS 1.1 jms.jar.

JMS 2.0 will work with JMS 1.1 code.

See the IBM MQ 9.2 Knowledge Center link [IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java applications>Using IBM MQ classes for JMS>Writing IBM MQ classes for JMS applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031950_.html).

> JMS 2.0 introduces a simplified API, while also retaining the classic API, from JMS 1.1.